# unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [turtlebot turtorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) but when I attempt to install the deb packages required, I get the apt-get error message "Unable to locate package".

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot ros-hydro-turtlebot-apps ros-hydro-turtlebot-viz ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator ros-hydro-kobuki-ftdi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot-apps
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot-viz
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-kobuki-ftdi
```

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 with `ros-hydro-desktop-full` installed from **sources**. I have the `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ saucy main` repository in my sources.list which I've already updated.

What haven't I done?  Would this have something to do with the fact that I've installed from sources?

Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194762/unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-turtlebot/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot tutorial explicitly states that you should install desktop-full from debs.

In particular, it depends on having the ROS deb repository set up and desktop-full installed from debs.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-10-12**:
Didn't read down the page far enough before I asked. ;)